# How can I list all http current connections from host running my program?

Tags: c#, .net, sockets

I want to list all the http active connections from the host, I'm using the code below, which lists any tcp connections, but I want to find specifically the http ones from this tcp list.

```
Console.WriteLine("Active TCP Connections");
IPGlobalProperties properties = IPGlobalProperties.GetIPGlobalProperties();
TcpConnectionInformation[] connections = properties.GetActiveTcpConnections();
foreach (TcpConnectionInformation c in connections)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} <==> {1}",
                      c.LocalEndPoint.ToString(),
                      c.RemoteEndPoint.ToString());
}
```

Comment: have you tried filtering on port 80?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Port `80` is the standard HTTP port, and port `443` is the standard HTTPS port. You might want to filter for both.

Change your `foreach` loop to the following:

```
foreach (TcpConnectionInformation c in connections)
{
    if ((c.RemoteEndPoint.Port == 80) || (c.RemoteEndPoint.Port == 443))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} <==> {1}:{2}",
                          c.LocalEndPoint.ToString(),
                          c.RemoteEndPoint.ToString(),
                          c.RemoteEndPoint.Port);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just because a TCP port is open doesn't mean only HTTP traffic will be traveling across it. Unless you have some other criteria to use in identifying a TCP connection as an "HTTP" connection, filtering for port 80 is probably as close as you're going to get.